# Improve textfield render performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React 17 and MUI 5. I found a problem in my project when I have a component with a huge form with multiple `<Textfields>`.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
};

...

<TextField
   value={this.state.value}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   label="Textfield"
/>
```

Everytime I type a char in my textfield the setState is triggered and my `render()` function is called everytime. So on my huge form I have a lag when I type.

So I tried the solution to use `onBlur` event:

```
<TextField
   onBlur={this.handleChange}
   label="Textfield"
/>
```

It works well if I'm on "Add" mode because the setState is triggered only when I leave the textfield. But I have a problem when I'm on "Edit" mode. When I'm on "Edit" mode I get the current value and I put it inside my textfield. And with `onBlur` event I can't use the textfield `value` prop because there is a conflict and I can't write anymore in the textfield.

So I found another solution. It's to use `ref`. But I have the same problem like with `onBlur` event. I can't use `value` prop. So I did this :

```
<TextField
   inputRef={(el) => {
     this.textRef = el;
        if (el && this.state.mode === "edit") {
          this.textRef.value = this.state.node.value;
        }
   }}
   label="Textfield"
/>
```

So when I'm on edit mode I init the textfield with the current value (this.state.node is a node of my [TreeView](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/) and each node have a edit button). This code works. But I have the feeling it's not the good way to do that. This `if mode == edit` is weird.

Do you have a better way ?

Comment: "Better" is in the eye of the beholder. Some people would have no problem with `mode == edit`; others might have a problem with refs. Please be clear on what you mean by "better" that doesn't depend on opinions, but rather facts. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: How big is your "huge form"? I just tried a quick benchmark with 1000 inputs / 100 `TextField`s (they are indeed much more expensive to render) and the performance is fine, at least on my machine. Are you doing something expensive in your `render()` function?

Comment: @Taxel Have you tested with react 17 and Mui textfields with onChange event ? My form has 60 inputs but I have the same problem with other component like treeview if I have more than 20 items

Answer (score 1):

You could examine uncontrolled inputs, it could fit in your case

An uncontrolled form doesn’t have state, so every time you type, your component doesn’t re-render, increasing overall performance.

There is an explanation: https://hackernoon.com/you-might-not-need-controlled-components-fy1g360o

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the "huge form" is actually the problem. React only updates the DOM when there are changes, so even though the component is rerendered on every character typed, only the one input field that changes should get flushed to the DOM.

Check if you're doing expensive calculations in your `render()` function. In that case, memoize these.

Another take on fixing this would be to use uncontrolled components as mentioned in the other answer.

Also consider if you can split up your component into multiple, smaller components so the problem is minimized.

The following "benchmark" code is written with functional components but is using MUI v5 and React 17 and runs with 100 `TextField`s without any noticable lag when entering text, at least on my (relatively beefy) desktop PC.
Using `<input>` from HTML even allowed me to get this working with 1000 elements.

```js
const inputFieldKeys = Array.from({
  length: 100
}).map((e, i) => "field_" + i.toString());

const App = (props) => {
  const [inputState, setInputState] = React.useState({});

  // this runs fine even without the `useCallback` optimization, at least for me
  const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setInputState(oldState => ({ ...oldState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  }, [setInputState]);

  return ( <div>
      {inputFieldKeys.map(key=>(
      <MaterialUI.TextField name={key} key={key} value={inputState[key] || ""} onChange={handleChange}
      label={key}/>
    ))}
  </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Note for MUI performance:
MUI v5 uses the `sx` prop for inline styling. This can lead to bad performance in cases with many components when used without care. [mui docs](https://mui.com/system/basics/#the-sx-prop)

Comment: You didn't notice the lag because you are typing slow I think. Try to type very fast you will notice the lag